# Erase drawing in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have written an Android application with a Canvas for drawing with a stylus. It works well. When I'm pushing the upper function key of my stylus I would like to erase the drawing by brushing over the text. The normal drawing is in black, so I thought to do the erase with white (on top of the black line). My problem is that all lines change the color when I press the upper function key of the stylus (i.e. all lines are then white) instead of just painting the new draw line in white.

Another option would be to delete elements from the path for the erase. If somebody has a solution for this, I would be happy too.

The layout looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="StylusBaselineA">

    <inf.ethz.ch.affectivestudy.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/baselineACanvas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `CanvasView` class look as follows:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

    public int width;
    public int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Path mPathErase;
    Context context;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mPaintErase;
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;
    private boolean erase = false;

    public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        context = c;

        // we set a new Path
        mPath = new Path();
        mPathErase = new Path();

        // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

        mPaintErase = new Paint();
        mPaintErase.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaintErase.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaintErase.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaintErase.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaintErase.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    }

    // override onSizeChanged
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    // override onDraw
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
        if (erase) {
            canvas.drawPath(mPathErase, mPaintErase);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }
    }

    // when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
    private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
        if (erase) {
            mPathErase.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        }
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    // when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values
    private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
            if (erase) {
                mPathErase.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            } else {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            }
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    public void clearCanvas() {
        mPath.reset();
        mPathErase.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    // when ACTION_UP stop touch
    private void upTouch() {
        if (erase) {
            mPathErase.lineTo(mX, mY);
        } else {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_ERASER) {
            // Upper function key of stylus
            erase = true;
        } else if (event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER) {
            // Touch input
            erase = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            erase = false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                moveTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upTouch();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess u should create new path on every startTouch event

Comment: @uguboz Thanks a lot. That was the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
    public class CanvasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Paint mPaint;

    View mView;
    Button clear;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear_layout);
        mView = new DrawingView(this);
        layout.addView(mView, new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        clear= (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);


    }

    public class DrawingView extends View {

        public int width;
        public  int height;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;

        private Path mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;
        public DrawingView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context=c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;

                circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```